# Attempt to access a harvested connection

Tags: oracle, hibernate, weblogic

i get this exception in my weblogic console : 
*

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Attempt to access a harvested connection
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Connection.checkHarvest(Connection.java:1676)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection.checkConnection(PoolConnection.java:108)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet.preInvocationHandler(ResultSet.java:93)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet_oracle_jdbc_driver_ForwardOnlyResultSet.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:950)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    ... 132 more
```

the weblogic version is : 12.2.1.2.0 
i think this exception maybe related to lazy loading , is it correct ? 
but finally i dont know what it is exactly.

Answer (score 4):

Check your Datasource configuration in WebLogic. Specifically:

- `Test Connections On Reserve` is **enabled** and also
- `Test Table Name` in **specified** as it is required to test physical database connection before reserve (I like to use `SQL SELECT 1 FROM DUAL` statement there).

What most probably happens, is that you have a closed "trusted" db connection in datasource pool. Checking/setting harvesting info to that connection was the first thing to fail on it.

References:

[Datasource properties - Advanced Configuration Options](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/FMWCH/pagehelp/JDBCjdbcdatasourcescreatejdbcdatasource2title.html)

[WebLogic JDBC Datasources](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/TASKS/jdbc.htm#TASKS694)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem is to enable Test Connections On Reserve. When Test Connections On Reserve is enabled, when your application requests a connection from the data source, WebLogic Server tests the connection using the query specified in Test Table Name before giving the connection to the application.

To enable Test Connections On Reserve, login to the Admin Console -> Navigate to the Data Source's Configuration -> Connection Pool -> (Advanced) -> check "Test Connections On Reserve"

Note: Enabling "Test Connections on Reserve" would have some performance impact on the application because the WebLogic will test the connection before passing it to the application which make application run a little slower. But the benefit of it is that application will not run into issue that a connection is not working due to being stale or other reasons. So there is a trade-off you would need consider.
After making the changes, restart the data source or the weblogic servers for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Oracle document](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/JDBCA/ds_harvesting.htm#JDBCA549)
when connection harvesting is enabled in Weblogic, all connections are initially marked harvestable and Weblogic pool  cleanup this connections.
I think when using hibernate in lazy mode hibernate  get connection from pool and execute first statement, when invoke getter method of lazy object , hibernate want to execute another select statement to load lazy objects but Weblogic harvested connection and this exception raise .

Comment: i dont think so , my connection pool connection count about 20 and the harvest trigger on 50 but already i take this exception